# Finding unused IP addresses

Tags: android, ftp, ip-address

I have tried searching for this, but nothing has met what I need so far. I am writing an FTP server application for Android, but I do not know how to find an IP address for the server that is not in use.

I have so far been guessing and hardcoding in an address. Sometimes it would work and sometimes it wouldn't. How can I get my app to consistently generate and connect to an open, usable IP address?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to know: how do you assign a ip addess to the Android?

Comment: Well, If your opening a ftp server from your android device there is actually noone that can connect to it. Sure your Android device have an ip address and one might thing, hej lets run a server, but there's no way to do it since a phone inter.prov, do some funky stuf with your ip address

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution to the problem is to obtain a DNS name (usually at a small expense), and then use a dynamic DNS service to keep telling the DNS hosting provider the current IP address for the DNS name.
Then clients can lookup your IP address from a well-known name.

There is also an indirect solution to the problem.  You can get a infrastructure provider to host the FTP service.  For example, you could run a free Amazon Web Services micro instance.  Whilst it is running it should be on a constant IP address.  Then both your clients and your app can use this as a fixed intermediate relaying point.  This also solves the transient nature of mobile devices which might not be available to respond at a particular time.